# public socks proxy over SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, netcat

So I'm able to create a local socks proxy with `sudo ssh -D 8080 user@server`
and I can access it only from my machine:

```
nmap -p 8080 127.0.0.1
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

However this proxy is not accessible from my local network:

```
nmap -p 8080 192.168.1.10
8080/tcp closed  http-proxy
```

I've tried port forwarding, however does not seem to solve the issue (unless i'm doing it wrong)
I'm on a Mac, btw.

Solutions?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access the SOCKS proxy from the network, you need SSH to bind its SOCKS proxy to an accessible, external address instead of localhost, which is "local" and doesn't allow any other external connections. Use this command instead:

```
ssh -ND "*:8080" user@server
```

Note that I've removed `sudo` from your command, and I've added the `-N` flag to the command. `sudo` is certainly not needed; you only need it if you're opening ports below 1024 (which you shouldn't unless you have good reason). The `-N` flag makes the SSH session **N**oninteractive so that you don't have a shell session launched, just a proxy. The `-D ":8080"` binds the SOCKS proxy to all addresses on the system, including network ones.

As for firewall settings, if you have a recent version of Mac OS X (10.6+), you may also want to open your firewall to your 8080 port. You can use this command to do so:

```
sudo ipfw add 9999 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 8080
```

`9999` is just a firewall ID number that you can use to identify firewall rules.

Should you decide to stop opening your proxy, this command will close it back up:

```
sudo ipfw delete 9999
```

After all of that configuration, if you want your proxy to be available across the Internet, you would then need to follow instructions to set up port forwarding. You can use [this guide](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) to configure port forwarding on your router.

**HOWEVER**... exposing an open proxy over the Internet can cause trouble. Your ISP will probably frown upon this, especially if someone not-so-nice accesses your SOCKS proxy over the Internet. A better solution? Install an OpenSSH server, secure it, and simply log in from the Internet and set up the SOCKS proxy locally. [This guide](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Instant_SOCKS_Proxy_over_SSH) can assist with that.

Happy proxying!